# How to Start Tomcat7 Not as Root

Tags: tomcat7, root

I do not want to have to run tomcat7 as root.

```
vagrant@dev$ /etc/init.d/tomcat7 stop
You need root privileges to run this script
```

Please tell me how to run tomcat7 as my current user, vagrant.

Note - if there's a lot of ugly configuration to achieve this, I am open to `sudo apt-get remove tomcat7` in Ubuntu, and then re-install tomcat7 from a .tar.gz file to a non-root directory.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: I am not a Tomcat user, but have you tried the ways mentioned under - [Tomcat wiki - how-to](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo#How_to_run_Tomcat_without_root_privileges.3F) - [David Ghedini's blog post (step 5)](http://davidghedini.blogspot.de/2011/02/install-tomcat-7-on-centos-rhel.html)

Answer (score 4):

Ubuntu's [documentation on Apache Tomcat](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/tomcat.html) has a section on [creating private instances for users](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/tomcat.html#tomcat-user). This is for Ubuntu 11.04, I updated the follow excerpt to use *tomcat7*:

> #### Installing private instance support
>
> You can install everything necessary to run private instances by
>   entering the following command in the terminal prompt:
>
> `sudo apt-get install tomcat7-user`
>
> #### Creating a private instance
>
> You can create a private instance directory by entering the following
>   command in the terminal prompt:
>
> `tomcat7-instance-create my-instance`
>
> This will create a new my-instance directory with all the necessary subdirectories and scripts. You can for example install your common libraries in the lib/ subdirectory and deploy your webapps in the webapps/ subdirectory. No webapps are deployed by default.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to be root to run Tomcat.  Just [download the Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) package, unzip or untar to your directory of preference, and launch tomcat from the bin directory:

```
<tomcatdir>/bin/catalina.sh start (or run)
```

You do, of course, need to have a copy of java installed and accessible by your user.  You can specify any custom bindings/paths in the /bin/setenv.sh file (such as JAVA_HOME, JAVA_OPTS, CATALINA_OPTS), etc.

Comment: I'd love to know why someone downvoted this response, when in fact, it is quite accurate.